# How to boot Ubuntu without a monitor plugged in?

Tags: boot, monitor

How to boot an Ubuntu 12.10 without Monitor/Keyboard/Mouse
I'm using as server and connect to it through Remote desktop viewer

No problem with 12.04 but after the upgrade I receive the message
Low Graphic or monitor not detected

I have try to create a /etc/X11/xorg.conf with multiple proposed solution from internet without sucess.

Comment: Seems not to work for 14.04

Answer (score 3):

What I have found as workaround, but when I plug a screen there is no more image

1. Install dummy monitor

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
   ```
2. Backup xorg.conf

   ```
   sudo  mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
   ```
3. Create a new xorg.conf

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```

with

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1152x864"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```