# Run without monitor in 12.10

Tags: xorg, monitor, remote-desktop

Yes I know this question is out there but none of the answers work for me like the ones found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234081/how-to-boot-ubuntu-without-a-monitor-plugged-in) and [here](http://olitee.com/2010/01/ubuntu-remote-desktop-without-a-monitor/).

I have Ubuntu version 12.10 32bit.
It's a fresh install. Only software installed is Teamviewer 8.
I'm trying to setup this computer so I can remotely access it but Ubuntu doesn't like to boot up without a monitor.

I've tried a couple xorg.conf edits. None of them work and I'm forced to do a reinstall of Ubuntu to fix what I messed up.

I have an old, almost 15 year old PC. It has an ASUS M2N-MX SE PLUS motherboard.
I believe the integrated video is something like an Nvidia GeForce 6100.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System Settings -> Displays, you can set the default monitor from there.

Fire up the remote monitor and hopefully Ubuntu will detect it.

Then set that monitor to the default one.

Reboot with the PC monitor off.

Ubuntu should come up on the remote screen and work fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ubuntu doesn't detect teamviewer as a monitor. what now?

Comment: I'll look into it. I'm a bit busy now.