# How to make Ubuntu 12.04 desktop session start on boot without a monitor plugged in?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, monitor, headless

I have a home server that I need to access via remote desktop, and I want to leave the server there without a monitor hooked up to it.  Everyday the server turns off and turns back on.  There is no monitor installed.

I find that my 12.04 64 bit installation, when booted without the monitor plugged in, just hangs on a screen that says the system will start in low-resolution mode.  It never actually starts up the desktop environment, which is what I need.  So it is impossible for me to remote desktop to the server after it is started.  This is the problem.

When I reboot with a monitor installed, the desktop session starts and everything is fine.

Is there a way I can configure the system to run the desktop session after every boot without a monitor installed?

---

I have looked around the net quite a bit.  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234081/how-to-boot-ubuntu-without-a-monitor-plugged-in) mentions that the desired behavior worked in 12.04, but I do NOT have this experience.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

i hope i understood that correctly, have a look at this post

[sudo service lightdm start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166009/use-ubuntu-graphical-desktop-without-monitor-at-boot)

"BillR" is telling something , that it is possible to boot only in text mode, or only in graph. mode.

Comment: This is true, but that post explains how to make Ubuntu start in command line only mode, not desktop only mode...